# Express state of overflow as function?

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra, function

Making an ALU I want a signal that signals whenever an addition or subtraction changes the binary number from - to +. Each number u and v is 4-bits and therefore is marked by 0, 1, 2, 3 where 3 is the most significant bit. c3 in this case is the carry in from the previous addition. z3 is the result and c4 is the potential carry out from the addition. I am using 2s complement, the list below explains how it works.

$$
1000\hspace{1cm} -8\\
1001\hspace{1cm} -7\\
1010\hspace{1cm} -6\\
1011\hspace{1cm} -5\\
1100\hspace{1cm} -4\\
1101\hspace{1cm} -3\\
1110\hspace{1cm} -2\\
1111\hspace{1cm} -1\\
0000 \hspace{1.5cm} 0\\
0001\hspace{1.5cm} 1\\
0010\hspace{1.5cm} 2\\
0011\hspace{1.5cm} 3\\
0100\hspace{1.5cm} 4\\
0101\hspace{1.5cm} 5\\
0110\hspace{1.5cm} 6\\
0111\hspace{1.5cm} 7\\
$$

As one can see here when adding for example 6 + 6. $$0110 + 0110$$ The result is 1100 i.e -4. Since that isn't correct the signal OF (overflow) will turn one signaling this. As you can see below in the completed truth table, OF = 1 only when u3 and v3 are the same and the carry signals have alternate values. When adding 0110 + 0110 u3 and v3 is 0, c3 will be 1 since u2 and v2 will have a result of 0 and a carry out of 1.

[image]

Now I wanna express the OF signal as a function. When trying I get this expression.
$$OF = u_3´v_3´c_3c_4´z_3 \vee (u_3´v_3´c_3c_4´z_3)´$$
This expression will always be equal to 1 since $$A \vee A´ = 1$$
Therefore I'm a bit lost in how to express OF as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your truth table for OF, it looks like you meant to write

$$OF = {u_3}' \, {v_3}' \, c_3 \, {c_4}' \, z_3 \vee u_3 \, v_3 \, {c_3}' \, c_4 \, {z_3}'$$

Remember that \$({u_3}' \, {v_3}' \, c_3 \, {c_4}' \, z_3)'\$ is not the same thing as \$u_3 \, v_3 \, {c_3}' \, c_4 \, {z_3}'\$.